# Post MM3 adventures

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures

I'm aware there has been a big shift in monster stats with MM3 and all the adventures that have been published before have weak encounters in them.

**Can you provide me with a list of D&D adventure modules that feature the revised, more challenging monsters?**
Which level do each cover?

Please provide links to the free ones.
Unofficial adventures are ok but please set them aside from the official ones. And I'm not a big fan of the Essentials line, so I'm not interested in those.